# Can't load AVD of api 22

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

Long story short: I'm trying to run an AVD with api level 22, Nexus 5, CPU (tried all 3 options - ARM, Intel Atom x86, Intel Atom x86_64), 2048 RAM, 1 GB internal memory, 500MB SD card, using host gpu.
And it takes the emulator about 20-30 minutes to load, and after every click takes about 10 seconds to respond, and also the resolution is a shit, the icon are getting on top of each other.
It happens only with high api level, if I'm using api level 19 it works a lot faster.. But I need api level 22 for using nativescript.

Long story:
I developed in the past for android using Java (with eclipse) and phoneGap and cordova.
But java isn't working for ios and phoneGap performance isn't like a native app.

So I searched and find NativeSctipt that supposed to build native apps in the final product.
I wanted to try it but it needs to be on api 22 and for some reason the emulator is not working good at all when using this api level.

Also I searched and I didn't find a way to connect another AVD to develop,
I wanted to connect one called Andyroid, but I couldn't connect it.
I don't wanna use Genymotion as it's not free for commercial use.

Hope you can help.

Update:
[screenshot of my installed HAXM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpN8t.png)

Comment: it seems to be that your computer has no support for Intel HAXM. Older APIs you would run on every PC, including 32-bit ones. As you don't want to get a Genymotion, you have only one choice: buy a Lollipop driven phone

Comment: How can I know if my computer supports Inter HAXM? What computer I need to get in order to have it supported?

Comment: run  your sdk manager and check if HAXM is intalled

Comment: yes, it's installed. I have a laptop with 2 graphic cards, is it possible my computer is using the wrong one? (one is nvidia geforce, and the other one is intel HD integrated graphic card)

Comment: add screenshot to get me to know that you have installed it. Also check answer below

Comment: genymotion is the better emulator, consider to support them if you earn money with your apps, I think its **absolutely** worth the price :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your computer is not compatible with `VT-x/HAXM` technology or you haven't already installed.

#### Open your Android Sdk manager.

1. Go to your `android-sdk` directory and choose `tools` folder.
2. Run `android` file.
3. Check if `HAXM` is installed

[image]

If it isn't installed try to install and check if it would show error dialog like 'your PC doesn't support VT-x technology'

If you're running Linux, you would need to install KVM. Here you would find instruction how to do it: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/03/12/how-to-start-intel-hardware-assisted-virtualization-hypervisor-on-linux-to-speed-up-intel-android-x86-emulator

#### Check if `Hyper-V` is running (only Windows)

If you're using Windows check [this](https://superuser.com/questions/540055/convenient-way-to-enable-disable-hyper-v-in-windows-8) and DISABLE Hyper-V if it is enabled

After that try to install `HAXM/KVM` again.

Hope it help

Comment: I updated my original post with a screenshot of my installed HAXM, also I tried to disable the Hyper-V but it said it's not recognized, so I guess it means it's also not activated.

Comment: After a lot of tries I guess my computer isn't strong enough to run this version of android, I will try again once I'll have stronger computer

Answer (score 0):

if your skds are up to date ....just creat your device with defualt RAM(1536) and VM heap (64) and it works :)